# Two formulas with different free variables not semantically equivalent

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I have two formulas. The first one with free variables $\{S\}$ is:

$$\forall x(x \in S \Rightarrow P(x))$$

The second one with free variables $\{x,S\}$ is:

$$x \in S \Rightarrow P(x)$$

I guess we do not have in first order logic:

$$\vDash \forall x(x \in S \Rightarrow P(x)) \Leftrightarrow (x \in S \Rightarrow P(x))$$

Here is an attempt of mine. I use a model where $P=\{<0>\}$. And then I find that for these assignments I get different truth values:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
x & S & \forall x(x \in S \Rightarrow P(x)) \\ \hline
0 & \{1\} & F \\
0 & \{0,1\} & F \end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
x & S & x \in S \Rightarrow P(x) \\ \hline
0 & \{1\} & T \\
0 & \{0,1\} & T \end{array}$$

Is this a way to show semantical inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not semantically equivalent in that -- for any given interpretation of $S$ and $P$ -- the first has only one truth value, whereas the truth value of the second depends on which value you give $x$.

For example, in your model with $S=\{0,1\}$ and $P$ being true for $0$ only, then your second formula is true sometimes, namely when $x=0$ (and in fact whenever $x\ne 1$) -- but with the same interpretation the first formula is simply false, period.

Comment: The second formula is not "true sometimes". If the model allows $x = 1$ then the formula is false in that model. Period.

Answer (score 1):

The semantics for those two formulas are arguably not even the same *sort* of thing, let alone the same thing.

For the usual set-theoretic semantics, the semantics of the first formula would be a $0$-ary relation, i.e. a subset of the set $D^0=\{\langle\rangle\}$ where $D$ is the domain we're working over. (We can identify "true" with $\{\langle\rangle\}$ and "false" with $\{\}$.) The semantics of the second formula, on the other hand, would be a unary relation, i.e. a subset of $D^1=D$. Generally, a formula with potentially $n$ free variables will have semantics as an $n$-ary relation, i.e. subset of $D^n$. Arguably, it shouldn't even make sense to *ask* whether two formulas with different potentially free variables have the same semantics, but set theory has a global notion of equality which lets you ask "nonsense" questions like whether $\pi=\mathbb Q$. In categorical or type theoretic semantics, it's quite easy and natural to arrange things such that asking whether the semantics of formulas with different sets of potentially free variables is simply not well-formed.

Now I've repeatedly said "*potentially* free variables". Consider a formula $P(x)$. It is clear that $x$ is free in $P(x)$, but we could also say that $y$ is free in $P(x)$ but it just happens not to occur. Usually we restrict "free variables" to the variables that actually occur hence my use of "potentially free variables". The significance here is that the semantics of $P(x)$ depend on whether we consider it a formula where only $x$ may occur freely or a formula where $x$ and $y$ may both occur freely (or any other collection of variables containing $x$). What we can do, then, is view your first formula as potentially but not actually containing $x$ free which would make its semantics comparable (even in a categorical or type theoretic semantics) to the semantics of your second formula. Even for the set-theoretic semantics, this is important. Let's say that you chose an interpretation for $S$, $P$ and a semantic domain $D$ such that your second formula held for every element of $D$. It's semantics would then be $D$ itself. In that case, it would also be the case that your first formula would hold and thus its semantics would be $\{\langle\rangle\}$. $D\neq\{\langle\rangle\}$, but if we viewed the first formula as having one, unused free variables, then, being a constantly "true" formula its semantics would also be $D$.

In the more general categorical semantics, this step of moving a formula from having one set of potentially free variables to having a larger set is not necessarily trivial. In traditional set-theoretic semantics it is often left completely implicit and not much discussed. This is a mistake. For example, the categorical understanding of the existential and universal quantifiers are intimately related to this operation of expanding the number of potential free variables. In fact, they are *characterized* by it. Specifically, they are left and right adjoint to it respectively.

Comment: Okay. I didn't know if you were treating $S$ as a constant symbol or what. It doesn't make a significant difference to my answer. You just get $D^2=D\times D\neq D^1=D$ instead of $D^1\neq D^0=\{\langle\rangle\}$. The issue is the same.

Comment: @j4nbur53 I was interpreting the question as whether/how to show two formulas are equivalent by comparing their interpretations. For $\vDash \forall x(x\in S\Rightarrow P(x))\Leftrightarrow (x\in S\Rightarrow P(x))$, there is only one formula and so there's nothing to compare. If you pluck out the two subformulas, then both being parts of the same formula, they should be treated as having the same potential free variables and thus would be comparable as I explained. The issues I mentioned matter for accurately understanding FOL and not just when making a proof assistant.

Comment: @j4nbur53 It is a *meta-theorem* that $\vDash P\Leftrightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $\mathcal I(P)=\mathcal I(Q)$ where $\mathcal I$ is some interpretation. It is not true by definition. And even to have it *be* true, you have to take into account the concerns I mentioned. For $(y=y\land P(x))\Leftrightarrow P(x)$, again, this is a single formula so there's nothing to compare. If you want to use the just mentioned meta-theorem, then it is important to treat $P(x)$ as having the *same* potential free variables as $y=y\land P(x)$ otherwise they *won't* have the same interpretation.

Comment: You're correct, I should have written something like $\mathcal I\vDash P\Leftrightarrow Q$.

Comment: @HarryStoteles Yes, I know. The continuing point of my answer and comments is that what constitutes an interpretation for a formula $P$ depends on what variables the interpretation needs to interpret. This must include the free variables of $P$ but *can* include additional variables. Arguably, it only makes sense to compare interpretations that interpret the same set of variables. To be more explicit, $\mathcal I_{\{x,y\}}(y=y\land P(x))=\mathcal I_{\{x,y\}}(P(x))\neq\mathcal I_{\{x\}}(P(x))$.

Comment: Thus it's important to use compatible variable sets even when it may include variables that don't occur in one formula as otherwise you may think $\not\vDash(y=y\land P(x))\Leftrightarrow P(x)$ because $\mathcal I_{\{x,y\}}(y=y\land P(x))\neq\mathcal I_{\{x\}}(P(x))$. Personally, I think it's best to talk about "formulas-in-context", i.e. to consider the variables that are allowed to occur in a formula as part of the data of a formula, and then parameterize $\vdash/\vDash$ by those "contexts" (i.e. variable sets).

Comment: @HarryStoteles I didn't say anything about multi-sorted FOL. I also explicitly said that set theories *do* allow you to write things like $\pi=\mathbb Q$, but that this doesn't really match mathematical practice. This comes up in more general approaches to semantics *of single-sorted FOL* (which include the set-theoretic semantics as a special case) where comparing interpretations for formulas with respect to different sets of variables is meaningless.

Comment: I agree $\mathcal I_{\{x\}}$ doesn't apply to $y=y\land P(x)$. My point is it's easy to conflate $\mathcal I_{\{x,y\}}$ and $\mathcal I_{\{x\}}$ when the distinction is ignored both notationally and in explanations of semantics. Whether $\mathcal I(P(x))$ should mean $\mathcal I_{\{x\}}(P(x))$ or $\mathcal I_{\{x,y\}}(P(x))$ or something else depends on context that is invisible and largely undiscussed in typical presentations of the semantics of FOL.

Comment: @HarryStoteles Why do you keep deleting your comments?